# how to declare and then initialize a parquet arrow::Rand omAccessFile in C++

Tags: c++, parquet, shared-ptr, apache-arrow

I am trying to readapt this piece of code of the parquet [C++ documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/parquet.html) to open a parquet file with a `FileReader` to get the minimum value of a column.

```
arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input;
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(input, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(path_to_file));

// Open Parquet file reader
std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> arrow_reader;
ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::OpenFile(input, pool, &arrow_reader));

// Read entire file as a single Arrow table
std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table;
ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(arrow_reader->ReadTable(&table));
```

However, the macro `ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE_ERROR` is causing the error:

error: cannot convert 'const arrow::Status' to 'int' in return

```
   27 |    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(input, arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(parquet_path.c_str()));
      |    ^
      |    |
      |    const arrow::Status
```

The [macro documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/support.html) says:

> Execute an expression that returns a Result, extracting its value into the variable defined by lhs (or returning a Status on error).

So I tried to do the passages explicitly separating the initialisation from the declaration, something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input(nullptr);
input = std::make_shared<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile>(arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(parquet_path.c_str()));
```

but I am getting the error

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'arrow::io::RandomAccessFile'
  146 |  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

How can I initialize the shared pointer of `arrow::io::RandomAccessFile` after the declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `std::make_shared`, `arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open()` returns a shared pointer.

```
std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile> input =
    arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(parquet_path.c_str()).ValueOrDie();
```

Comment: In this case I am getting `error: conversion from 'arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::ReadableFile> >' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::RandomAccessFile>' requested
   19 |     arrow::io::ReadableFile::Open(parquet_path.c_str())`

Comment: Oh I need `*.ValueOrDie()` right?

Comment: I likely used an obsolete manual. Yes, as for the actual [manual](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/io.html#_CPPv4N5arrow2io12ReadableFile4OpenERKNSt6stringEP10MemoryPool), it returns a tuple `Result`.

Comment: Can you please paste the reference to the manual? I am having some difficulties finding C++ documentation on arrow